# Jquery setInterval on slider with progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar, setinterval

I have implemented something like this so far, please check jsFiddler demo : http://jsfiddle.net/semantic/6SaJK/1/

I want to set this on timer (i.e) jquery setInterval. and also want the "**progress-bar**" to 
to move from 0width to 100% width with the timmer.

Here is the example how I want it: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/slide.html.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

First thing that comes to mind is to use [JQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate a `div` that resizes from 0 width to full size using the same time interval that you use in your time out

---

Alternatively, you can skip the `setInterval` part and just use the callback parameter of the `animate` function. [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/a8DxF/)

Comment: @Green, check my edit with working sample! (I assume you are after another solution because I didn't originally put any code for you to copy?)

Comment: thanks for your time musefan, please don't take it like this way. I wanted to work with the existing code, which is already been placed. I will have a look, if I can work around your PASTED CODE.